# geom_tile color for each row and facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
ggplot(
  data.frame(
    inh = c(
      1, 1, 1, 1, 
      2, 2, 2, 2, 
      3, 3, 3, 3, 
      4, 4, 4, 4
    ),
    
    buck = c(
      1, 2, 3, 4, 
      1, 2, 3, 4, 
      1, 2, 3, 4, 
      1, 2, 3, 4
    ),
    
    gender = 
      c(
        "m", "m", "m", "m", 
        "m", "m", "m", "m", 
        "m", "m", "m", "m", 
        "m", "m", "m", "m", 
        
        "f", "f", "f", "f",
        "f", "f", "f", "f",
        "f", "f", "f", "f",
        "f", "f", "f", "f"
      ),
    
    share = 
      c(51, 34, 10, 3, 
        42, 34, 13, 8, 
        33, 26, 19, 13, 
        38, 24, 19, 16,
        
        49, 20, 20, 10, 
        30, 30, 30, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 70, 
        25, 25, 25, 25)
  ),
  aes(x = inh, y = buck, fill = share)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = share)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = 1, type = "seq") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gender))
```

It creates heatmap and it works fine, except that I would like assign color for each row and column. For example facet “f” and x axis “4”, value 25 looks the same for each “buck” because my code took highest value - 75 and lowest one - 3 and created gradient for values between.

But for each row and facet I would like to achieve something like this.

```
ggplot(
  data.frame(
    inh = c(
      1, 2, 3, 4
    ),
    
    buck = c(
      3, 3, 3, 3
    ),
    
    gender = 
      c(
        "f", "f", "f", "f"
      ),
    
    share = 
      c(20, 30, 10, 25)
  ),
  aes(x = inh, y = buck, fill = share)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = share)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = 1, type = "seq") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gender))
```

Comment: So, you want each row a different color, but the color doesn't depend on `share`, only the row it is in (also your example shows different colored columns, not rows). Difficult to know exactly what you want here

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're asking here. It's certainly possible to get a colour for each row and facet, as the question title suggests. Are you looking for something like this?

```r
ggplot(data,
  aes(x = inh, y = buck, fill = as.factor(interaction(buck, gender)))) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = share)) +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gender)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]